# Не получается занести значения из edit в stringgrid

Tags: delphi-7

Мне необходимо занести значения из Edit1 в StringGrid1 по нажатию enter но по нажатию значение из первой колонки удаляется и туда записывается новое:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
var x: string;
   i,j:integer;
begin
x:=Edit1.Text;
if Key = #13 then
begin
  x:=Edit1.Text;
  StringGrid1.Cells[0,1]:=x;
   Edit1.Clear;
 x:=Edit1.Text;
  StringGrid1.Cells[0,2]:=x;
  Edit1.Clear;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А как должно быть?

Comment: по первому нажатию enter число записывается в ячейку, по второму в следующую и т.д.

Comment: то есть я забиваю значение в edit, нажимаю enter, и значение заносится в первую ячейку, далее снова забиваю значение в edit нажимаю enter и значение заносится в следующую ячейку

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записывать в следующую ячейку, надо запоминать её номер.

В глобальных переменных или поле формы:

```
 sgcount: integer = 1;
 ...

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
if Key = #13 then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[0,sgcount]:= Edit1.Text;
      Inc(sgcount);
      Edit1.Clear;
   end;
end;
```